# Add dynamic buttons in grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to add 225 (15x15) buttons on my grid. I created rows and columns. Then I created dynamically buttons. I'm trying like this

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication15.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Grid Name="gridMain" ShowGridLines="True" >

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication15
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                {
                    Button MyControl = new Button();
                    MyControl.Content = i.ToString();
                    MyControl.Name = "Button" + i.ToString();

                    gridMain.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, j);
                    gridMain.Children.Add(MyControl);

                }
                gridMain.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i);
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
        }


    }
}
```

But I see this:

[image]

When I want to see this:

[image]

Comment: Everything seems ok, you just need to set the Column and Row using Grid Class i.e. "Grid.SetRow(someLabel, 0);". @Wimmel has given perfect answer

Comment: Thanks, i solve this

Answer (score 8):

Thanks!

I resolved this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication15
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int count = 1;


            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                {
                    Button MyControl1 = new Button();
                    MyControl1.Content = count.ToString();
                    MyControl1.Name = "Button" + count.ToString();

                    Grid.SetColumn(MyControl1, j);
                    Grid.SetRow(MyControl1, i);
                    gridMain.Children.Add(MyControl1);

                    count++;
                }

            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;

        }


    }
}
```

[image]